# |UNITY 3D| Target Lock Error. No Reason I can find

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am attempting to make a lock on feature for my Third Person Game. With the script I am using I get varying effects. Usually it works normally off and on. However at seemingly random points it no longer locks on. Sorry if it is a bit messy. I was up and over testing different points.

```
public class PlayerLockOn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool lockOn = false;
    float maxLockDist = 65;
    List<GameObject> availableTars = new List<GameObject>();
    float shortestDist = Mathf.Infinity;
    public GameObject closestLockOnTarget;
    public GameObject currentTarget;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Get Input
        if (lockOn)
        {
            GetTargets();
            ManageTargets();
            if (currentTarget == null)
            {
                
                CameraMovement.instance.camRecenter();
                lockOn = false;
            }
            else
            {
                PlayerStateManager.instance.camState = 1;
                CameraMovement.instance.lockOnTarget = currentTarget;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            availableTars.Clear();
            currentTarget = null;
            CameraMovement.instance.lockOnTarget = null;
            closestLockOnTarget = null;
            PlayerStateManager.instance.camState = 0;
        }
        
    }
    void GetTargets()
    {
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 25);

        for (int b = 0; b < colliders.Length; b++)
        {
            var tag = colliders[b].tag;

            if (tag == "Enemy")
            {
                
                Transform tarTransform = colliders[b].transform;
                Vector3 TargetDir = transform.position - tarTransform.position;
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(tarTransform.position, transform.position);

                if (PlayerStateManager.instance.Player.transform.root != tarTransform.root &&  distance <= maxLockDist)
                {
                    availableTars.Add(colliders[b].gameObject);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void ManageTargets()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < availableTars.Count; i++)
        {
           
            
            float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, availableTars[i].transform.position);

            if (dist <= shortestDist)
            {
                shortestDist = dist;
                closestLockOnTarget = availableTars[i];
                currentTarget = closestLockOnTarget;

            }
        }
    }

    public void lockOnUpdate()
    {
        
        lockOn = !lockOn;
        
    }
}
```

I have tried moving around how I get the target to different points. This has not had much of an effect. Though when I move my character around I can sometimes get it back on one more time depending on the angle of the character. However there isnt a reference to this in the code so I dont know why it has that effect. Other than that I have no other issues with it. It is quite reliable. I just need to add on a visual check to make sure its visable most of the time. Thank you if you do look over it, just trying is a big help.

Comment: in general in `GetTargets` you might be calling each frame ... sure you want to add the targets potentially multiple times? Might rather want to use a `HashSet` to ensure you only add targets that are not still in the list already anyway

Comment: Also you never seem to reset `shortestDist` so it might stop working after some time

Comment: derHugo was right. It was constantly setting a shorter location as the minimum as my character moved forward. Thanks Hugo.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're implementing LockOn feature while it is separated from existing CameraMovement object, so you using singleton pattern for them to communicate. Instead, if you make one object to control another, on in simple cases just add functionality to the existing class with similar responsibility:

   ```
   class CameraController {
       ...
       public LockOnTarget(Transform target){...}
       public void StopLockOn(){...}
   }
   ```
2. Target search shouldn't be responsibility of LockOnFeature nor CameraMovement objects, instead create separate TargetSearcher behavior with its own logic. Also, doing spherecasts in Update() is not very good idea - there is already a physics engine, let it do its stuff using triggers and just subscribe to its events to update your HashSet (don't use Lists for constant add/remove stuff, they are slow at this).
3. Use UnityEvent and UnityEvent<T> to communicate between your MonoBehaviours. `public UnityEvent<int> OnDamageReceived;` and the ability to hook up any method of any other script through Editor is much, much better than all those pesky singletons which are quickly making your app rigid and hard to change, while also maintaining developer's bad habit.
4. Developer's Golden Rule: Don't invent where you could use accessible solution. Install Cinemaching using `Window -> Package Manager` menu, get into user manual for a bit and you could change your camera perspective, procedural view motion and scripted paths with zero code written. Write your own cool camera controller that could do this and that just is good to get experience and figure out some math behind, but if you need working solution - use whatewer the World offers, it wuold just save your time.